# MySQL apt-get install not installing

Tags: software-installation, mysql

When trying to install MySQL with the Bash command line using apt-get install it does not work.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
root@raspberrypi:~# clear
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,283 kB/8,305 kB of archives.
After this operation, 89.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main mysql-common all 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libmysqlclient18 armhf 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main mysql-client-5.5 armhf 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main mysql-server-core-5.5 armhf 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main mysql-server-5.5 armhf 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main mysql-server all 5.5.52-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Edit:
Tried --fix-missing and tried update (and upgrade). Nothing worked. Is there an alternative download for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to literally follow the suggestion given in the error message (ephasis below):

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe **run apt-get update** or try with --fix-missing?

So still staying logged on as `root` execute:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get update
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install mysql-server
```

This time APT will fetch version 5.5.53 instead of the 5.5.52 removed from the repository.

As a general rule, you should always use `apt-get update` before installing packages.

Comment: Tried --fix-missing and tried update (and upgrade). Nothing worked. Is there an alternative download for MySQL?

Comment: That's strange because I tested on a fresh Raspbian, got the same error as you, ran `apt-get update` and the problem was resolved on next `apt-get install mysql-server`.

Comment: You don't need any alternative download, you just need to ask for the correct files. You've got everything on your screen - navigate to http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5 with your browser and you will see the packages (in 5.5.53 version).

Comment: I tried running apt-get install mysql-server multiple times and still doesn't work!

Comment: You do realise your comments are not particularly constructive, right?

Comment: I figured our what I need to do to install it. It's probably just a bug with the OS. Thanks for the feedback.